# MongoDB -Match condition is not working properly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I just need to fetch the data from the mongodb using a condition 
Condition is i want to get all the data from the mongodb till today .Please see my code below
match = {[{"lastUpdatedTs": {"$lte": datetime.datetime(2018,10,04)}}]}
and i have tried 
match = pricing_data.find({"lastUpdatedTs":{"$lte":end_date_range}})
..both is not working for me

Please suggest a valid condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which format you store lastUpdatedTs? String or mongo Date? If second, you should try

```
pricing_data.find({ lastUpdatedTs: { $lte: new Date() } })
```

Comment: i did that . how should i use it in in my aggregations as i am using to flatten the array fields . Please find my code ////results = pricing_data.aggregate([{"$unwind" : "$sta"},{"$unwind" : "$states.covs"},{"$unwind" : "$states.xxxx.yyyyy"},{"$unwind" : "$states.xxxx.yyyy.zzzzzs"}, {"$match" : match}, {"$project": project}])///// where match is pricing_data.find({"UpdatedTs":{ "$lte":datetime.datetime(2018,10,04)}}) project is colmn names task is that i need to write this filtered json data in to a hive table .. I could do that but the count differs with the matching condition

Comment: i stored the condition in match attribute